# What is the probability of finding passwords in hackers dictionary?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose passwords are allowed to be 8 bit long and to use 128 characters so total combinations are $(128)^8$ which is basically $2^{56} $. Now total passwords contained in the password file, being hacked, is $2^{10}$. The Hacker has a password dictionary of $2^{20}$ common passwords. The probability that the password is in dictionary is $\frac{1}{4}$ but when I try it I get$\frac{2^{30}}{2^{56}}$.
Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: I suspect the $1/4$ is an empirical result: perhaps a quarter of all passwords actually used can be found in a dictionary of $2^{20}$ common passwords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that encrypted passwords are mostly salted, we can calculate with them independently.

We can assume that people has completely random passwords, which is surely not true, but in a math view, it is okay. Thus, we can calculate with a level distribution.

The hackers chance to find a match for a single password entry is $\frac{2^{20}}{2^{56}}$.

Thus, his chance to *not* find it, $1-\frac{2^{20}}{2^{56}}$.

Thus, his chance to *not* find anything in the $2^{10}$ passwords, is $(1-\frac{2^{20}}{2^{56}})^{2^{10}}$.

Thus, his chance to find a match is $\underline{\underline{1-(1-\frac{2^{20}}{2^{56}})^{2^{10}}}}$.

Note, considering that $\frac{2^{20}}{2^{56}}\ll1$, you can approximate $(1-\frac{2^{20}}{2^{56}})^{2^{10}}$ with $1-2^{10}\frac{2^{20}}{2^{56}}$, which is $1-\frac{1}{2^{26}}$.

Using this approximation, the result is $\frac{1}{2^{26}}$.

Comment: The answer is 0.25 not $\frac{1}{2^{26}}$. kindly refer [this link page 23](https://www.os3.nl/_media/2013-2014/courses/ssn/ssn_lecture_10_authentication.pdf).

Comment: @Ankit I think the answer in the book is false. The writer doesn't show his calculation, only declares the 1/4. The reason, why are the chances so low, is that the $2^{56}$ possible combinations are very high compared to the $2^{20}$ tries. Offtopic: In the reality, the hacker has really a very good chance to find a match, but it is because users don't like to use passwords like "Aechai8ZtahKae8a", instead they prefer "kate123" and similar.

Comment: Oh! so you are saying that the result is based on some behavioral pattern of the people having password, known to the hacker.

Comment: @Ankit Yes, but it is not a math thing. In the mathematical side, we've calculated as if users would use all the 128 characters, in their maximal length, completely randomly, in level distribution. 1) It is exactly the opposite what users tend to do 2) In such a system, password dictionaries would be useless. <- It is a conceptional fault in the book.